# Why is the datepicker opening automatically?

Tags: angularjs

With the below code, my datepicker is always open and I don't see the input area:

HTML:

```
<td ng-controller="notificationModalController">
    <span><strong>End Date</strong></span>
    <input type="text" name="notification.text" ng-model="notification.text" datepicker="">
</td>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('datepicker', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
        $(el).datepicker({
            autoclose:true,
            onSelect: function (dateText) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

I'm using this theme in case it matters:

http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0T41TX4

Why would the datepicker always be open?  I'd like for it to behave like the one in the theme sample but this is the closest I've gotten:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstraper datepicker dont provide the method onSelect. Try something like this instead:

```
el.datepicker({
    startDate: new Date(),
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    autoclose: true
}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
    someVar = e.date;
});
```